# jQuery fadeOut() overwriting fadeIn() if Ajax call takes less than 200ms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fadein, fadeout

I have the following HTML, CSS and Javascript:

**HTML**

```
<p id="loading">Loading...</p>
<div id="my-box"></div>
<input type="button" id="my-button" value="Click" />
```

**CSS**

```
#loading {
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#my-button").click( function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: {html: "<p>Text echoed back to request</p>"},
        delay: 0,

        beforeSend: function(xhr) {

            $('#loading').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $('#my-box').fadeOut();
            });

        },

        success: function(html){

            $('#my-box').stop(true, true).html(html).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                $("#loading").fadeOut("fast");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

There is a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/masimao/560Ldvqe/10/) here.

The problem is if the ajax call takes less than 200ms to execute, fadeOut() overwrites fadeIn() and `#my-box` become invisible instead of visible.

I am not seeing what can cause this. Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: [fast](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has a duration of 200 MS. If the AJAX call finishes before that, then the Success function will fire before the callback function of `$('#loading').fadeIn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same sequence in *success* for `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`

```
success: function (html) {
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $('#my-box').html(html).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/zc7dogkv/)

Comment: I am trying to solve this since yesterday, you save my life! Thanks! One last question, do you know exactly why it happens if we use a different sequence for `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`?

Comment: @MarcioSimao, Its nothing to do with ajax, fadeIn() and fadeIn() are added to queue, so which ever is added first executed first.